# Is the Microsoft C Run-Time Library a superset of the ISO C standard library?

Tags: c, c-standard-library

The POSIX C library is a superset of the ISO C standard library.

Does the Microsoft C Run-Time Library implement

- exactly the ISO C standard libary
- a superset of the ISO C standard library
- something else?

Comment: Read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are plenty of Microsoft extensions, but I've also heard that there are some newer functions (from C99 or C11) that Microsoft doesn't support yet, meaning that their RTL is neither a subset nor a superset of ISO.

Comment: MSVC is not standard compliant. It does not implement required features an some function follow their own way. If you need standard compliance (which is a good idea), use a different implementation & environment.

Comment: Posix is an operating system api, that has little to do with the standard C library.  It compares to the Winapi.  The plain standard library is not typically good enough to write practical programs, it models a very primitive teletype-based single-threaded machine so everybody does add extensions.

Comment: @HansPassant, the standard defines a minimal common denominator, which is primitive. POSIX offers a richer environment (also falls short), Windows goes it's own way.